# How to make this function can be run on linux?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

```
//convert mbs to utf8 string
bool MultiChar2UTF8(const char *inp, string& strOut){
{`enter code here`

    char *outp = NULL;
    wchar_t *poutw = NULL;
    try
    {
        if(NULL == inp)
        {
            LOG_ERROR("MultiChar2UTF8 input invalid potinter");
            return false;
        }

        poutw = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(strlen(inp) + 1));
        if(NULL == poutw)
        {
            LOG_ERROR("MultiChar2UTF8 malloc failed.");
            return false;
        }

        memset(poutw, 0x00, sizeof(wchar_t)*(strlen(inp) + 1));
        if(0 == ::MultiByteToWideChar(936, MB_COMPOSITE, inp, -1, poutw, strlen(inp)))
        {
            int e = GetLastError();
            free(poutw);
            poutw = NULL;
            return false;
        }

        int size = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, poutw, -1, NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);
        if(0 == size)
        {
            free(poutw);
            poutw = NULL;
            return false;
        }

        char *outp = new (std::nothrow)char[size + 1];
        if(outp == NULL)
        {
            free(poutw);
            poutw = NULL;
            LOG_ERROR("MultiChar2UTF8 new char failed.");
            return false;
        }

        if(0 == ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, poutw, -1, outp, size + 1,               NULL, NULL))
        {
            free(poutw);
            poutw = NULL;
            delete []outp;
            outp = NULL;
            return false;
        }
        strOut = outp;
        free(poutw);
        poutw = NULL;
        delete []outp;
        outp = NULL;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        if(NULL != poutw)
        {
            free(poutw);
            poutw = NULL;
        }

        if(NULL != outp)
        {
            delete []outp;
            outp = NULL;`enter code here`
        }
        LOG_ERROR("Function MultiChar2UTF8 Exception...");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where does `imp` and its content come from? Are you sure the conversion is necessary on Linux too?

Comment: oh sorry,  bool MultiChar2UTF8(const char *inp, string& strOut) ; it's the function define

Comment: I just noticed this isn't even about Microsofts "wide chars" Unicode stuff, but GBK936. ... Either use ICU http://site.icu-project.org/, or write your own conversion function based on the data of http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT . First byte >127 means there is a second byte. After converting to raw unicode numbers, covnerting to UTF8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description